# Me da este error y no se por que es : URIs must begin with 'https://' or 'http://' or 'data:

Tags: html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="background-color:rgb(0,255,0)">BIENVENIDOS AL SERVIDOR DE GREAT GREEN!</h1>
<p> <a href="https://pokemonshowdown.com/rules">Por favor, respeta las normas de la comunidad.</a></p>

<img src="pp.png" alt="Logo" width="128" height="128">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, añade más información a la pregunta: ¿Dónde te da ese error?¿En el navegador?¿En la consola de JavaScript?¿En qué línea?

Comment: Hola @Nacho. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! No veo nada mal en la página. ¿En dónde lo estás probando y dónde es que se está disparando el error? ¿Esto es lo único que tenés de código en un html subido a una web? ¿O hay algo más que no estás mostrando? ¿Qué navegador estás usando?

Comment: Tu código funciona perfectamente. ¿Hay algo más de código que estés utilizando?

Comment: Holahola buenas el error me sale cuando inserto la imagen, pues lo demás funciona perfectamente,soy nuevo en este lenguaje, posiblemente sea algo muy tono,que no consigo ver, ese es el código completo

Comment: ¿Si pones `./pp.png` funciona?¿y si pones la url completa a la imagen (http://tudominio.com/pp.png) funciona? Y aparte, ¿tienes control sobre el servidor?

Comment: @NachoOchaitadelRio lamentablemente esta pregunta no aporta nada a la comunidad SOesp. Este post debiste abrirlo en los foros de pokemonshowdown.com. Por favor, cierra y/o elimina tu pregunta y traslada tu problema a los técnicos del site.

Answer (score 1):

Una simple búsqueda en Google nos lleva a [esta página en GitHub](https://gist.github.com/dracomageat/5f24a03ac3d3ce932e7e6e42f0499f11)

En concreto, tu error se produce en esta parte del código:

```
canEmbedURI(uri, isRelative) {
    if (uri.startsWith('https://')) return uri;
    if (uri.startsWith('//')) return uri;
    if (uri.startsWith('data:')) return uri;
    if (!uri.startsWith('http://')) {
        if (/^[a-z]+\:\/\//.test(uri) || isRelative) {
            return this.errorReply("URIs must begin with 'https://' or 'http://' or 'data:'");
```

Revisa el uso que estás haciendo de esta función, pues parece que como indica el  mensaje de error, no está recibiendo el comienzo de cadena (URI) que espera.

**EDICIÓN:**

El problema es que cualquier URI que utilices en ese código HTML, debe estar precedido de `http://`, `https://` o `data:`.

Para solucionar el problema sustituye:

```
<img src="pp.png" alt="Logo" width="128" height="128">
```

por la ruta completa hasta tu imagen:

```
<img src="http://www.miservidor.com/pp.png" alt="Logo" width="128" height="128">
```

No te olvides de incluir `http://` o `https://` por delante del nombre de la imagen.

Un saludo

Comment: Hola buenas, sigo sin encontrar el error, sé dónde está pero no veo el fallo, básicamente por qué no he usado URI nunca

Comment: El código que pegas es tan sólo una página web estática, lo cual no conforma en si mismo ninguna _aplicación_. El editor de la librería te indica el uso de la misma, como por ejemplo: `CommandParser.parse("/join lobby", room, user, connection)` . ¿Cuando estás recibiendo este error? ¿Al hacer que cosa?

Comment: Al añadir la parte de cogido de la imagen, por lo demás todo va perfectamente

Comment: Supongo que ese `pp.png` estará en internet alojado en algún sitio, no?

Comment: Hola gracias, ya no me sale el error, pero la imagen como tal no sale, sale el cuadrado con la interrogación y el alt

Comment: no, el png esta en mi computadora, supongo que ese es el fallo pero no se

Comment: El png tiene que estar alojado en internet para que tu navegador pueda mostrarlo. Si no tienes ningún alojamiento, elimina esa parte del código. Por favor, cierra y/o elimina esta pregunta. Suerte.

Comment: okey, error solucionado ya funciona correctamente mil gracias

Comment: Genial! Mucha suerte